# How to stop a if for a second before executing the rest of the commands

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I been working on a script for a pause menu and i don't know how to make it stop before start executing the next line
This is the code, i ask for this because execute the "if" multiple times, because detects that i'm still pressing the Cancel button. (I use c# and work on Unity 5)
Thanks

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MenuPausa : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject menuPausa;

private bool pausaMenu = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cancel") || pausaMenu == false) {
        menuPausa.SetActive (true);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        WaitForSeconds(1); 
        pausaMenu = true;
    } else {
        menuPausa.SetActive (false);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        Invoke("waiting",0.3f);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/379440/a-simple-wait-function-without-coroutine-c.html

Comment: Perhaps Thread.Sleep(). Although, I'm not sure what the point of this would be. Are you trying to do some type of polling?

Comment: Maybe this will help if you want to do some type of polling. http://sstut.com/csharpdotnet/javascript-timers-equivalent.php

Comment: Says that yield doesn't exist in the current concept

Answer (score 1):

I would use a coroutine kinda like this:

```
bool paused = false;

void Update ()
{
    if (paused) // exit method if paused
        return;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("PauseButton")) 
        StartCoroutine(OnPause()); // pause the script here
}

// Loops until cancel button pressed
// Sets pause flag 
IEnumerator OnPause ()
{
    paused = true;

    while (paused == true) // infinite loop while paused
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cancel")) // until the cancel button is pressed
        {
            paused = false;
        }
        yield return null; // continue processing on next frame, processing will resume in this loop until the "Cancel" button is pressed
    }
}
```

This only "pauses" and resumes this individual script.  All the other scripts will continue executing their Update methods.  To pause the frame rate independent methods (i.e. physics), set Time.timeScale = 0f when pausing and back to 1f when unpaused.  If pausing all the other scripts is desired and they're dependent upon frame rate (i.e. Update methods) then use a global pause flag instead of the local paused variable used in this example and check to see if the flag is set in each Update method, like in this example.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if I'm misunderstanding this, but it seems to me like you're opening and closing a pause menu using the "Cancel" button, and that your script seems to be immediately closing it after opening it due to the "Cancel" button still being pressed. It also seems to me that this script is intended to be a component of the menu object that is being turned on and off. If that is the case, I would suggest the following:

Have this script be used on an object other than the menu itself (such as a MenuManager object or something - also I would change this script's name to MenuManger to avoid confusing it with the actual menu) that will remain active in the scene. Have a PauseMenu object in the scene that gets assigned to this MenuManager's "menuPausa" property. I would then remove the pausaMenu variable. Also, make sure this script is added as a component to ONLY the one object (the MenuManager), otherwise a second object might update in the same frame and turn the menu right back off.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the method, put

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

It pauses the execution for 1000 miliseconds == 1 second.
Is this simple solution enough or do you need a more complex one with a Timer?

Comment: Don't work, i want to stop the if method so i can hold the pause menu

Comment: Now I don't understand your goal. Is it that you want to keep the Cancel button pressed but let the Update() method to react only once?

Comment: What i want to do is:
That when i press esc set to active a game objet, until there i can do it by my self, but then if i use `if(Input.GetButtonDown("Cancel"))` Detects like if i was still holding the esc button

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer, insert it from the toolbar, change the interval which is in milliseconds, then once thats done use the scripts `timer.Start();` and `timer.Stop();`
thats what i used.